# AUTOSAR: It is recommended to call directly a runnable from Scheduler?

Tags: runnable, rte, autosar

I'm discovering the AUTOSAR world.

My question is about code:

I have understood  that the SW-C runnables are called from the RTE by using RTE APIs, according to events (init, timing, datareceive).
Is it possible to call directly a runnable (like we call a function) from the scheduler, for example after a  synchronous event (example at the TopDeadCenter of an engine).
I think this will "override" the RTE, is it hazardous to proceed like this?

Comment: To be better able to propose a solution, beside the general information already given in the answers below, please provide examples how your SW gets informed about the events.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to circumvent something the RTE does, you're probably not designing things as intended by Autosar.

Calling SWC runnables directly is a pretty big violation of the concept. Runnables are schedulable entities, intended to be scheduled by the OS, indirectly through the RTE. A runnable should be activated by the RTE in response to an RTEEvent, or multiple such events.

Circumventing the RTE will violate the concurrency and reentrancy guarantees the RTE provides, as well as the data consistency guarantees the RTE provides regarding any data read/written by the runnable.

If you want to call a runnable in response to an event, and this event is detected by some other SWC, you're supposed to use Client/Server communication. Your runnable would become an Operation on the server, and would be called via a call point. In this case, "Client-server communication" is what you should look up in the specification to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to go around RTE, as it does way more than just dispatching calls.

Take a look at the layered structure of AUTOSAR Architecture; your RunnableEntity (Application) and the BSW Scheduler (System Services) are "two floors away". So don't. :)

Comment: Yes, you confirm what I thought. So, when the event occur, should I use the DataReceivedEvent (which implies the schedules has a provider port for a variable) or should I use the SwcModeSwitchEvent ?

Comment: ModeSwitch-es will only work within an ECU, not sure if that is what you need.

Comment: Such runnables are unofficially called "Server-side Runnables"; create a port with ClientServerInterface (with at least one corresponding Operation) and an OperationInvokedEvent in your internal behavior. The 'startOnEvent' role shall point to the RunnableEntity you wish to call. It's the caller's (client component) responsibility to make the call synchronous by declaring a SynchronousServerCallPoint in the invoking runnable. Most the server can do is specify the call-queue length in a ServerComSpec. (And also, declare the started runnable as non-concurrent.)